# cannot connect as .\SQLEXPRESS, but can with (local)/SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to connect to SQL server.
I can connect with `(local)/SQLEXPRESS`, `"my pc name"\SQLEXPRESS`,
but I cant connect as `.\SQLEXPRESS`
it needed cause all connection string in developed environment are starts with `.\SQLEXPRESS`

I've tried to restart services, but it didn't help.

Comment: And what is the exact error message that you get?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Please, make sure your instance name is correct (is the same as those used when connecting to `"my pc name"\SQLEXPRESS`). Retype it if needed. If it was due to network connectivity issues, you should get the same when using computer name. When you get the error, click "Show technical details" and copy/paste the details here. Highly unlikely, but check is SQL Browser server running (it should, because you can connect using pc name). Download [PortQry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832919) and post the results of this command `portqry.exe -n youpcname -p UDP -e 1434`

Comment: Are SQL Server Browser is running?

Comment: @Aidanpraid `\ ` is the string escape character in most languages though, including C#. Where did the connection string come from? A config file or a string in the source code? Did you try connecting with SSMS? What does your actual code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue.

Issue was found in configuration manager. by some reason, installer have added me aliases